# R How to reference a macro variable within the code to make it part of a new dataset name

Tags: r

In sas, macro variables are prefixed with &, in stata, they're prefixed with `.
How do i reference a macro variable in R?  These both run without error, but since i can't get cylinder number to be part of the created dataset name, when i run it a second time, it overwrites the first one.

I want to get two datasets, x6 and x8

```
mtcarsdf <- data.frame(mtcars)

bycyl <- defmacro(df, cylnum,
                     expr={

                      xcyclnum <- subset(df, cyl==cylnum, select=(-c(carb, gear, am, vs)))

                     })

bycyl(mtcarsdf,6)
bycyl(mtcarsdf,8)
```

Comment: R does not use macros. It uses proper meta-programming instead. Also it's not good form to create "loose" variables with data in their name in your global environment. A better way to do something like this is R is list `split(mtcarsdf, mtcarsdf$cyl)` which will split the data set into a named list in R which is much easier to work with. It's important not to try to translate code from one language to another line by line. R is a functional programming language so proper code in that style will look very different than declarative code from other languages.

Comment: And if you really wanted just those two cylinder values, you could do `lapply(c(6,8), function (n) subset(mtcarsdf, cyl==n, select=(-c(carb, gear, am, vs))))` with base R, again, to get a list of values rather than separate variables.